# How to query two tables that have the same field, that returns id only if field value is the same

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (email and phone) that indicate if a message was opened (read/listened).  I need to find the id's of the member's who have not opened the message (they could have been sent an email and called).  So the only case in which they did not receive the message is if they did not open the email or answer the phone.

I have a query that looks like this to know if they opened it:

```
SELECT person_id, last_name, first_name
      FROM person 
     WHERE person_id IN (
          SELECT DISTINCT person_id 
          FROM (
            SELECT person_id
              FROM msg_email WHERE message_id = ? AND opened = 'Y'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT person_id
              FROM msg_voice WHERE message_id = ? AND opened = 'Y') tt
         )
 ORDER BY last_name ASC, first_name ASC"
```

However, this only works for knowing if it was opened via either of the delivery methods.

How would I fashion a query to find the person ids of those that received the message (exists is one of the two tables), but the opened value is 'N' exclusively in both tables?

Sample Data
person table

```
person_id  firstname lastname
    1         Joe       Smith
    2         Tom       Jones
```

msg_email table

```
message_id  person_id  opened
    1            1       N
    1            2       Y
```

msg_phone table

```
message_id  person_id  opened
    1            1        N
    1            2        N
```

So I need a query that will only return Joe Smith

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Why do you use the condition `...AND opened = 'Y'` in your code if you want "the ids of the members who have **not** opened the message"?

Comment: Added sample data as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, one method is a series of `EXISTS`/`IN` conditions:

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.last_name, p.first_name
FROM person p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM msg_email e
              WHERE e.person_id = p.person_id AND e.opened = 'N'
             ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM msg_email e
                  WHERE e.person_id = p.person_id AND e.opened = 'Y'
                 ) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM msg_voice v
              WHERE v.person_id = p.person_id AND v.opened = 'N'
             ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM msg_voice v
                  WHERE v.person_id = p.person_id AND v.opened = 'Y'
                 )
ORDER BY last_name ASC, first_name ASC;
```

I recommend `EXISTS` over `IN` because it usually has better performance.  That will be true if you have indexes on `msg_email(person_id, opened)` and `msg_voice(person_id, opened)`.

EDIT:

It occurs to me that you want `'N'` in either table along with no `'Y'` in both tables.  The logic is similar but:

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.last_name, p.first_name
FROM person p
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM msg_email e
               WHERE e.person_id = p.person_id AND e.opened = 'N'
              ) OR
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM msg_voice v
               WHERE v.person_id = p.person_id AND v.opened = 'N'
              )
      ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM msg_email e
                  WHERE e.person_id = p.person_id AND e.opened = 'Y'
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM msg_voice v
                  WHERE v.person_id = p.person_id AND v.opened = 'Y'
                 )
ORDER BY last_name ASC, first_name ASC;
```

Comment: Gordon, thank you so much!  Your last update was exactly what I needed.  Certainly one of the more challenging queries I have needed to produce.

Comment: Gordon, the solution did require one more set of parens to separate the exists conditions from the not exists conditions.